# Push variable from Spark to Airflow

Tags: pyspark, airflow

I have a variable which value I 'd like to be pushed to Airflow so I can use it as an input for the next task. I know that I must use xcoms but I haven't figured out how to push from the spark task to the Airflow

```
def c_count():
    return spark_task(
        name='c_count',
        script='c_count.py',
        dag=dag,
        table=None,
        host=Variable.get('host'),
        trigger_rule="all_done",
        provide_context=True,
        xcom_push = True
    )





 def c_int():
        return spark_task(
            name='c_in',
            script='another_test.py',
            dag=dag,
            table=None,
            host=Variable.get('host'),
            trigger_rule="all_done",
            counts="{{ task_instance.xcom_pull(task_ids='c_count') }}"
        )
```

EDIT:
The spark task is the following:

```
def spark_task_sapbw(name, script, dag, table, host, **kwargs):

    spark_cmd = 'spark-submit'

    if Variable.get('spark_master_uri', None):
        spark_cmd += ' --master {}'.format(Variable.get('spark_master_uri'))
.
.
.


    task = BashOperator(
        task_id=name,
        bash_command=spark_cmd,
        dag=dag,
        **kwargs
    )
    return task
```

The problem is that what I get back is the last print of the Airflow's log. Is there any way that I can get a specific value from the spark script? Thank you!

Comment: You’ll have to to provide more information here: to which Airflow Operator does the ` spark_task` map. Additionally, which executor is Airflow using?

Comment: You can persist the data between airflow task in to a key/value store like redis cache. Collect the data in spark driver from RDD and store into redis store. Inside airflow DAG connect to redis store and get the stored parameter. Use it in the next required task in airflow.

On the other hand if your airflow server is running in the same node where you submit your spark driver, then you can simply write to file after collecting and read the file again in the next airflow task

Answer (score 2):

You cannot make directly spark and airflow communicate. You have to use Python in between. [`collect`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.collect) the values you need and push them to airflow with XComs.

Comment: Exactly what I was afraid of! Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelGerm Your main problem will be that you use pyspark with a bash command. Airflow is in python, so you should include the spark packages and have your pyspark code directly running in airflow with a python operator. That'd be easier to transfert any wanted data.